# Is there a way to save the instance of a variable during debugging to reuse?

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-studio

I am debugging something and I end up in a function that takes as parameters a keymap with many key-value pairs.
I would like to be able to reproduce this exact flow but I would be interested in re-using this exactly map (I mean the contents).
The map is populated by other parts of the program and going over the parts or somehow "copy/pasting" the values from the debugger is tedious. I thought there might be a standard solution to this.
Is there a way to somehow save the instance of the keymap and somehow create it in another program? Like serializing in a file I guess and reading in the file

Comment: Is that a bad Idea make a special class to save the instance, if necessary use a Singleton test.

Answer (score 0):

Writting your keymap in a file is a solution. You can use JSON format to easily convert it.

Comment: Well I was interested if there is already an automatic way/hack in the debugger. If I have to write a program to save the file in JSON and read it back in my self, I might as well copy/paste the values from the debugger to a map definition in another class file